# Compiles on VS 2012 but not with Netbeans/MinGW - Overloading <<

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, netbeans

I'm having an issue with a program I am writing. I'm writing this project with visual studio because I find it easier to work with but I need to hand it in as a netbeans project.

I have the following issue:

I'm overriting the ostream << operator to output the book object in a certain format as you can see below

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const Book &book) {
//output stream
output  << book.author
        << ", \"" << book.title
        << "\" (" << book.pages
        << " pp.)";
//returns the output stream.
return output;
}
```

This code compiles fine in my visual studio project but on netbeans I get the following errors:

```
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=                    SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/My   Documents/NetBeansProjects/LibraryProjectCoursework'
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-    Windows/libraryprojectcoursework.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/LibraryProjectCoursework'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Book.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Book.o.d" -o     build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Book.o Book.cpp
Book.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const  Book&)':
Book.cpp:50:13: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are   'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const char [4]')
         << ", \"" << book.title
         ^
Book.cpp:50:13: note: candidates are:
Book.cpp:47:10: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Book&)
ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const Book &book) {
      ^
Book.cpp:47:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const char   [4]' to 'const Book&'
In file included from    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:52:0,
             from Book.h:3,
             from Book.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:2753:5: note:   template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT,   _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
 operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
 ^ 
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:2753:5: note:      template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Book.cpp:50:16: note:   mismatched types 'const std::basic_string<_CharT,  _Traits, _Alloc>' and 'const char [4]'
         << ", \"" << book.title
            ^
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Book.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/My     Documents/NetBeansProjects/LibraryProjectCoursework'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/My    Documents/NetBeansProjects/LibraryProjectCoursework'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2MSYS-1.0.10 Build:2004-03-15 07:17
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=00000000
eax=00000000 ebx=60EA31E4 ecx=00301E9E edx=60EA31E4 esi=00000000  edi=60EA00D4
ebp=0028FD40 esp=0028FD14 program=c:\msys\1.0\bin\mkdir.exe
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
End of stack trace
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you missing a `#include "Book.hpp"` statement? Also you show your errors here as verbatim text, not by linking screenshot images.

Comment: I can't seem to get the error to format correctly, and I do include Book.h but I get a In File Included From warning.

Comment: _"I can't seem to get the error to format correctly"_ You either use code or citation formatting (personally I prefer the 1st option).

Comment: Sorry, I've now added in code formatting for the error and removed the link to the image.

Comment: Are you including all the headers you need? <string> <iostream> etc

Comment: including <iostream> solved the issue, thank you. But why do I not need to include <iostream> when I compile the project in VS?

Comment: VS tends to be more tolerant than other compilers, for better or worse.

Comment: @Thody - If you're using `<iostream>` definitions, then you must include `<iostream>`.   Doesn't matter if it happens to compile now without it -- it may not compile in a future version of VS.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's complaining about not having an overload definition for `std::ostream<char>` and `char[]`, so the problem would be `out << "string literal"`. That doesn't sound like something you'll be able to fix, so you'll have to change the code to remove the string or somehow assign the string to a variable that it *does* have an overload for, like maybe wrap it in a `std::string`.

Edit: Wow, can't believe I didn't think about `including` the defined overload. SMH.

Comment: I don't think that. I think his compiler thinks that.

Comment: I'm guessing because whoever wrote that standard library didn't implement that overload? There may be a deeper reason, but I for sure don't know it.

Comment: Considering how basic such a functionality is, I find it very unlikely.